# summing check boxes and checking if a bit is set in php

Tags: php

I need to use two functions, one sums the values of checkboxes and I put that value into a cookie for one of many checkboxes used for a search page on a website.

The second function checks if the bit is set and I have no idea what this function is supposed to be doing. I know what it should do but I don't see it actually doing anything in the function.

All of the values are powers of 2 and it is supposed to see if the summed number contains that power of two. Below is the function:

```
function isBitSet($power, $decimal)
{

    if((pow(2,$power)) & ($decimal))
    {       
            return 1;
    }
    else
            return 0;

}
```

Comment: `pow` returns `arg1` raised to the power of `arg2` e.g. 2^2 = 4. Your function seems to be an elaborate way of checking whether the variables sent to it are set (boolean true), and in the first case, is a number. Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php

Answer (score 0):

`&` is the bitwise AND operator (not to be confused with `&&`, which is a comparison operator)! `&` compares the thing on its left and the thing on its right, bit by bit, and only outputs a `1` for each bit where BOTH inputs bits had a `1`. I'll show an example:

In the following example, the top number is `pow(2, $power)`, where `$power = 3`. It's written in binary form to make it clearer: doing 2 to the power of 3 has shifted a binary `1` right 3 places.

```
  00001000   <- this is pow(2, 3)
& 01101010   <- this is your $decimal (in binary form)
  ========
= 00001000
```

You see? All the output bits are 0, except where BOTH input bits were 1.

What we have done is we have used `pow(2, 3)` as a MASK: it has cleared EVERY bit to 0, except the one we are interested in (bit 3). That bit will be 1 if `$decimal` contains this particular power of 2, otherwise it will be 0:

```
$decimal contains that power of 2 -> result will be 00001000
$decimal does not contain that ^2 -> result will be 00000000
```

Since any non-zero integer evaluates to `true` in PHP, the `if` will occur if that bit is set (i.e. `$decimal` contains that power of 2), and the `else` will occur if that bit is not set (because the `&` will result in an output of `00000000`).

Please comment if you need any of that clarified. Hope it helps.